# Trouble to find element depending from other element in testcafe page object model

Tags: testing, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe, pageobjects

Having problems implementing the locator lookup method depending on its parent in POM

Example of DOM (roughly):

```
<div class="lessons">
  <div [data-test="lesson"]>
    <div class="lesson__info">
      <div ...>
        <h2 [data-test="lessonTitle"]>FirstLesson</h2>
    <div class"lesson__data">
      <div [data-test="lessonDataButton"]>
    <div class"lesson__controls">
      <div [data-test="lessonStartButton"]>
  <div [data-test="lesson"]>
    <div class="lesson__info">
        <div ...>
        <h2 [data-test="lessonTitle"]>SecondLesson</h2>
    <div class"lesson__data">
      <div [data-test="lessonDataButton"]>
    <div class"lesson__controls">
      <div [data-test="lessonStartButton"]>
```

Example of my POM:

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe'

class Page {
  constructor() {
    this.lesson = Selector('[data-test="lesson"]')
    this.lessonDataBtn = Selector('[data-test="lessonDataButton"]')
    this.lessonStartBtn = Selector('[data-test="lessonStartButton"]')
    this.lessonTitle = Selector('[data-test="lessonTitle"]')
  }

async getLessonButton(title, lessonButton) {
    const titleLocator = this.lessonTitle.withText(title);
    const currentLesson = this.lesson.filter((node) => {
      return node.contains(titleLocator())
   }, { titleLocator });
   
  const buttonSelector = currentLesson.find((node) => {
    return node === lessonButton();
  }, { lessonButton });
  return buttonSelector;
  }
```

In my test I'm trying to click "lessonDataButton" in specific lesson filtered by its "title":

```
await t.click(await schedule.getLessonButton(testData.lesson.data.title, page.lessonDataBtn))
```

It works correctly only for first occurrence of "lessonDataBtn" on page, but if I try to find the same button in second lesson - it will be an error:

```
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

       > | Selector('[data-test="lesson"]')
         |   .filter([function])
         |   .find([function])
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an example using the code samples you provided and got a different error:

```
1. The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.
 
    | Selector('[data-test="lesson"]')    
    | .filter([function])
  > | .find([function])
```

But I believe the case is the same: the `lessonButton()` call in the filter function of the `find` method of the `currentLesson` selector will always return the first node of the set. A straightforward solution is to search for the button directly with the css selector: `const buttonSelector = currentLesson.find('[data-test="lessonDataButton"]');`. You also can get rid of filter functions completely:

```
getLessonButton (title) {
    return this.lessonTitle.withText(title)
        .parent('[data-test="lesson"]')
        .find('[data-test="lessonDataButton"]');
}
```

Comment: Yes, your soultion was a fallback. The filter() option was preferable for me, because the lesson ([data-test = "lesson"]) has different buttons (4-5 buttons, depending on the state of the lesson) and I wanted to pass them as Selector() without changing the current page model.